# How to keep package-level kotlin functions in proguard?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-proguard

I declared a package-level function as utility in my library and I want to use it in my main app.

My issue is that I am not able to keep it from code obfuscation using proguard (and consequently use it in my main app).

My file it.blabla.util.Extensions.kt

`fun foo(context: Context, action: String) {
    ...
}`

I already tried to keep it in proguard using:

`-keep class it.blablabla.util.UtilPackage.** { *; }`

or

`-keep class it.blablabla.util.** { *; }`

but none of these is working.

In my app I'm trying to use foo as follows:

`foo(applicationContext, "test")`

but I'm not able to find the right import to let foo become visible in my app through the aar module.
I keep getting the following compilation error:

Unresolved reference: foo

Comment: The name of the class containing your extension method will be it.blabla.util.ExtensionsKt. The *Package class names existed in early pre-release versions of Kotlin.

Comment: Why do you use ProGuard on a library?

Comment: @yole, using -keep class it.blablabla.util.ExtensionsKt.** { *; } does not work.

Comment: @Miha_x64, I have to obfuscate my library code. So I have to use proguard when I compile for release.

Comment: Reading ProGuard docs is so easy. `-keepclassmembers class it.blablabla.util.ExtensionsKt.** { <methods>; }`

Comment: @Miha_x64 I tried `-keepclassmembers class it.blablabla.util.ExtensionsKt.** { <methods>; }` but the main app doesn't see the fun. I tried to import it as `it.blablabla.util.foo` or `it.blablabla.util.ExtensionsKt` but none of them is working

Comment: Make sure your ProGuard config file is specified in the buildscript; take a look at output jar.

Comment: @Miha_x64 yes, it is, I already specified other options to keep other classes and they are satisfied. My only issue is with this package-level method

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have to keep the the class as well as keeping the metadata ([proguard doc](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/languages/kotlin)):

```
-keep class it.blablabla.util.ExtensionsKt {
  *;
}
-keepkotlinmetadata
```