# Cannot keep class name for Kotlin functions inside AAR

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

I have an AAR library to use in several Android applications. It was written most in Java but I want to rewrite some utils pseudoclasses in Kotlin to make further development easier. But when I did so calls from the other places have been broken. For example, previously it was something like this:

```
/*inside library project, Java*/
package com.example.library

public interface Utils {
    static int functionOne() { return 1; }
}

/*inside application project, Kotlin*/
package com.example.app
import com.example.library.Utils

class SomeClass {
    private val myOne = Utils.functionOne()
}
```

But when I rewrite `Utils` into Kotlin functions file I cannot use it like this anymore. [Documentation says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) that it should be easy. So approach below breaks the code outside:

```
@file:JvmName("Utils")
package com.example.library

fun functionOne() : Int = 1
```

And there is no more `com.example.library.Utils.functionOne` when I include AAR to my application, only `com.example.library.functionOne` which is pretty different signature, so every class in Java or Kotlin using `Utils` outside AAR should be updated. But I still can call function like `Utils.functionOne()` within my library project. Also if I use different approach via `object` signatures would be kept, but redundant definitions would be generated too.

```
package com.example.library

object Utils {
    @JvmStatic
    fun functionOne() : Int = 1
}
```

So I think that the issue concerns some **proguard** definitions. And [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818000/how-to-keep-package-level-kotlin-functions-in-proguard) does not help, even my IDE highlights `-keepkotlinmetadata` in red telling that flag is invalid, neither works `-keep class kotlin.Metadata`.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of assumptions. Did you check what's *actually* happening? Just look at the generated class files: If the function is there, you have a different problem. If it's not, Proguard removed it.

Comment: Function are still here, as I say before, but it's the **class** which is not visible anymore. If I use _object_ approach there is `Utils.class`  and in decompiled class all's well.  When using _functions_ approach it is also here and all functions are present, but no class `Utils` in decompiled `Utils.class` file (but it is shown in `Utils.decompiled.java` view), so old imports are broken

Comment: That's not possible. Java has exactly one `.class` file per class. If there's a `Utils.class` file, there's a `Utils` class. So "no class Utils in decompiled Utils.class file" can't be true.

Comment: Sorry, my description was not accurate. Please see [screenshots here](https://imgur.com/a/JB6NPQ4). So the class is visible in Java code, but not in Kotlin code. Maybe it is designed to be like this but not so well documented, and I am missing something in concepts.

Comment: So is the question simply "Why does the Java-decompiled code have a `Utils2` class while the Kotlin code does not"? Then the answer is simple: Kotlin supports top-level functions outside classes, and Java does not. So the Java decompiler cannot generate valid Java source code without generating a class around it.

Comment: Close, but not exactly. The question is "Why Kotlin cannot access top-level functions the same way Java does, additionally to its own way?".

Comment: Because that's not how Kotlin works. To Kotlin, that class does not exist. It only exists for Java, and then only because it has to.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please write this as answer so I would accept it?